# Error message isn't displaying at the good place

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying for hours now to debug my jQuery error function (success too).
I don't understand how can I display an error message only below the button I click.
To help you to understand my problem, I made a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/P5PRP/)

here is the HTLM part :

```
<div class="leblock">
        <strong>Title</strong> some text<br />
        <form  id="panier_1" method="post" action="">
        <input type="submit"  value="0130280001" />
        <div id="txtHint_1"><b>data will spawn below</b></div>
        <div> <span id="error_1" style="display:none; color:#F00">DIV 1 NOT OK</span>
         <span id="success_1" style="display:none; color:#0C0">OK</span></div>
        </form>
</div>        
     <br /><br /><br />
<div class="leblock">
        <strong>Title</strong> some text<br />
        <form  id="panier_2"    method="post" action="">
        <input type="submit"  value="0130280002" />
        <div id="txtHint_2"><b>data will spawn below</b></div>
        <div> <span id="error_2" style="display:none; color:#F00">DIV 2 NOT OK</span>
        <span id="success_2" style="display:none; color:#0C0">OK</span></div>
        </form>
</div>
```

and jQuery :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('[id^="panier_"]').on('submit',function(e) {

        $.ajax({
            url:'panier.php',
            data:$(this).serialize(),
            type:'POST',
            success:function(data){

                $('[id^="success_"]').show().fadeOut(2000);                 
            },
            error:function(data){
            $("span:first-child").show().fadeOut(2000); //===Show Error Message====
            }
        });
        e.preventDefault();         
    });       
});
```

Any advice will be greatly aprreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the problems you have is that you don't have a reference to the button that you pressed from the form submit handler. One solution is to attach a click handler to the submit buttons to keep track of the last submit button pressed, and use that as a reference point to find the appropriate error message location.

I've updated your fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/P5PRP/1/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var submitButtonPressed = null;
    $('input[type=submit]').click(function() {
        submitButtonPressed = this; 
    });
    $('[id^="panier_"]').on('submit',function(e) {
        console.log(e);
        var $this = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            url:'panier.php',
            data:$this.serialize(),
            type:'POST',
            success:function(data){
                if (submitButtonPressed) {
                    $(submitButtonPressed).closest('form').find('[id^="success_"]').show().fadeOut(2000);               
                }
            },
            error:function(data){
                if (submitButtonPressed) {
                    $(submitButtonPressed).closest('form').find("span:first-child").show().fadeOut(2000); //===Show Error Message====
                }
            }
        });
        e.preventDefault();         
    });       
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would add a class to your error span of "error" and maybe move the style to the class, like this:

```
<style>
  .error {display:none; color:#F00}
</style>

<span id="error_1" class="error">DIV 1 NOT OK</span>
```

Then you can access that from your function like this:

```
error:function(data){
        $(this).siblings(".error").show().fadeOut(2000); //===Show Error Message====
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be solved by hiding the div with id "txtHint_" or you may even change the inner HTML of this div with id "txtHint_".

I hope this helps.